# find a closed form formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{2k}^2 - x_{2k-1}^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $\{x\} = x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ be the fractional part of $x$. Order the (real) solutions to $\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor \lfloor x^3\rfloor} + \sqrt{\{x\}\{x^3\}} = x^2$ with $x\ge 1$ from smallest to largest by $x_1,x_2,\cdots$. Provide a closed form formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{2k}^2 - x_{2k-1}^2}.$

First, I'm not even sure why there are infinitely many solutions to $\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor \lfloor x^3\rfloor} + \sqrt{\{x\}\{x^3\}} = x^2$. One inequality that might be useful is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. There's also the AM-GM inequality. We have $ac + bd \leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$ for all real numbers $a,b,c,d$ where $ac,bd\ge 0$ with equality iff $(a,b),(c,d)$ are proportional vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Observe that $\lfloor x\rfloor$ always has the same sign as $x$, so $\lfloor x\rfloor \lfloor x^3\rfloor$ has the same sign as $x^4 \ge 0$. It might be useful to substitute $\{x\} = x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ into the original equation and simplify the result somehow. Also, it could be possible to write the given sum as a telescoping sum.

Comment: Umm... First, you can think about $x \in \Bbb{Z}$, so that we know that there are infinitely many solutions to $\sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor \lfloor x^3 \rfloor} + \sqrt{\{x\}\{x^3\}}=x^2$.

Comment: The solutions must satisfy
$$\frac{\{x \}}{[x ]} =\frac{\{x^3 \}}{[x^3 ]} $$
for all $x \geq 1$

Answer (score 2):

Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$\frac{\{x\}}{\lfloor x\rfloor}
= \frac{\{x^3\}}{\lfloor x^3\rfloor}$
or
$$\lfloor x^3\rfloor = x^2 \lfloor x\rfloor. \tag{1}$$

Clearly, $x=1, 2, \cdots$ are solutions of (1).

Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.
Consider the solutions of (1) in $(k, k + 1)$ i.e. $k < x < k + 1$. We have $\lfloor x \rfloor = k$.
Let $u = k(x^2 - k^2)$.
We have $x = k\sqrt{1 + u/k^3}$
and $x^3 = (k^3 + u)\sqrt{1 + u/k^3}$.
We have
$x^2\lfloor x \rfloor = k^3 + u$.
Thus, $u$ is an positive integer.

(1) If $u \ge 2$, we have
$$x^6 - (k^3 + u + 1)^2
= \frac{(u-2)k^6 + [2(u-2)^2 + 6(u-2) + 3]k^3 + u^3}{k^3} > 0$$
which results in
$\lfloor x^3\rfloor \ge k^3 + u + 1 > k^3 + u =  x^2 \lfloor x\rfloor$.

(2) If $u = 1$ i.e. $x = k \sqrt{1 + 1/k^3}$, we have $x^3 = (k^3 + 1)\sqrt{1 + 1/k^3}$.
It is easy to prove that
$\lfloor x^3 \rfloor = k^3 + 1$.
Also, $x^2 \lfloor x\rfloor = k^3 + 1$. Thus, $x = k \sqrt{1 + 1/k^3}$
is a solution of (1).

Thus, we have $x_{2k-1} = k$ and $x_{2k} = k\sqrt{1 + 1/k^3}$ for $k = 1, 2, \cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a corrected version of my initial post, which solved an other problem. Please consider accepting the good and first answer of [River Li](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/584414/river-li), it is all what is needed for the solution.

---

Well, we have to find all solutions to the given peculiar equation, then compute the series. Let
$$
x = n+s\ ,\qquad\ n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 1}\ ,\ s\in[0,1)\ ,
$$
be a solution of the given equation.
Observe that $$s=0\ ,\qquad x=n\ ,$$
a natural number, is always leading to a solution.
Which are the other solutions, i.e. those with
$$s\in(0,1)\ ?$$
As mentioned by OP and [River Li](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/584414/river-li), using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for $a,b,c,d$ being the square roots of $[x]$, $[x^3]$, $\{x\}$, $\{x^3\}$, we obtain:
$$
x^4=(ac+bd)^2\le (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=([x]+\{x\})([x^3]+\{x^3\})
=x\cdot x^3=x^4\ ,
$$
so we have equality, so the vectors involved are proportional,
$$
\tag{$*$}
\frac{\{x\}}{[x]}
=
\frac{\{x^3\}}{[x^3]}\ .
$$
Let us see with a pedestrian approach which are the possible solutions $x=1+s\in(1,2)$, $s\in (0,1)$. Then $x^3\in (1,8)$, so $[x^3]$ is among $1,2,\dots,7$, so one of the following cases occurs from $(*)$:

- $1>s=(1+s)^3-1>0$, no solution, zero excluded,
- $1>2s=(1+s)^3-2>0$, so $2(1+s)=(1+s)^3$, and $s=\sqrt 2-1$ is the/a solution,
- $1>3s=(1+s)^3-3>0$, so $3(1+s)=(1+s)^3$, but $s=\sqrt 3-1$ makes $3s>1$,
- $1>4s=(1+s)^3-4>0$, so $4(1+s)=(1+s)^3$, but $s=\sqrt 4-1=1$ is too big,
- $1>5s=(1+s)^3-5>0$, so ... and $s$ is too big,
- $1>6s=(1+s)^3-6>0$, so ... and $s$ is too big,
- $1>7s=(1+s)^3-7>0$, so ... and $s$ is too big.

Continuing the pedestrian approach, let us find solutions $x=2+s$ in $(2,3)$. Then $(*)$ leads to one of the cases:

- $1>\frac 12\cdot 8s=(2+s)^3-8>0$, no solution, zero was excluded,
- $1>\frac 12\cdot 9s=(2+s)^3-9>0$, so $\frac 92(2+s)=(2+s)^3$,
  and $\sqrt {9/2}-2$ is a solution,
- $1>\frac 12\cdot 10s=(2+s)^3-10>0$, so $\frac {10}2(2+s)=(2+s)^3$, but the solution $s=\sqrt{10/2}-2\approx0.236067977\dots$ is not satisfying $1>\frac12 \cdot 10s$, so we reject it,
- $1>\frac 12\cdot 11s=(2+s)^3-11>0$, so $\frac {11}2(2+s)=(2+s)^3$, but the bigger solution $s=\sqrt{11/2}-2\approx0.34520787991\dots$ is not satisfying $1>\frac12 \cdot 11s$, so we reject it, too, and for the same reason the further cases also lead to invalid values for $s$.

So let us work in the general case. Denote by $m$ the number $[x^3]$ for a solution $x=n+s$, $s\in(0,1)$. So $n^3\le m<(n+1)^3$. Then $(*)$ becomes
$$
\frac sn = \frac{(n+s)^3-m}m\ .
$$
Equivalently:
$$
1>\frac 1n sm = (n+s)^3-m >0\ .
$$
Add $m$ in the equality, so $\frac 1n(n+s)m=(n+s)^3$, so $\frac 1nm=(n+s)^2$, so $s=\sqrt{\frac mn}-n$. And we check the needed condition $1>\frac 1nsm$, which becomes:
$$
\begin{aligned}
n&>sm\ ,\\
n&>\left(\sqrt{m/n}-n\right)m\ ,\\
(m+1)n&>m\sqrt{m/n}\ ,\\
n^3&>\frac{m^3}{(m+1)^2}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Considered as a function of $m$, the R.H.S. is increasing, for $m=n^3$ and $m=n^3+1$ the inequality is true, but starting with $n^3+2$ we have the opposite inequality:
$$
n^3(n^3+3)^2=n^9 + 6n^6 + 9n^3<n^9+6n^6 + 12n^3 + 8 = (n^3+2)^3\ .
$$

---

In conclusion, the solutions are $1,2,3,4,\dots$, the natural numbers $\ge 1$,
and intercalated between
$\sqrt{2/1}=\sqrt{(1+1^3)/1}$,
$\sqrt{9/2}=\sqrt{(1+2^3)/2}$,
$\sqrt{28/3}=\sqrt{(1+3^3)/3}$,
$\sqrt{65/4}=\sqrt{(1+4^3)/4}$,
and so on.
So the question wants us to compute the sum
$$
\begin{aligned}
S(n) &=
\sum_{1\le k\le n}
\frac1{\frac 1k(1+k^3) - k^2}
=
\sum_{1\le k\le n} k
=\frac 12n(n+1)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks for the quick poin... i had the bad equation on the paper... I'm deleting the answer, trying to rewrite..

Answer (score 0):

Let $u$ be a noncubic integer with $\lfloor\sqrt[3]{u}\rfloor = n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Assuming $\sqrt[3]{u} \le x < \sqrt[3]{u+1}$, we can reformulate the equation as follows.
$$ \sqrt{nu} + \sqrt{(x-n)(x^3-u)} = x^2 $$
Squaring both sides, we have
$$(\sqrt{n} x - \sqrt{u})^2 = 0$$
Hence the equation holds for $x = \sqrt{u/n}$ if $\sqrt[3]{u} \le \sqrt{u/n} < \sqrt[3]{u+1}$. Since the first inequality always holds, we only need to check which $u$ satisfies the second inequality. After calculating some examples, it is easy to guess that
$$u = n^3, n^3+1$$
are only $u$ we find. You can show this guess by substituting $u$ by $n^3+k$ for $k=0,1,2$, and checking that
$$f(u) = u^3 - n^3(u+1)^2$$
is increasing for $u \ge n^3+1$.